# Cascade value for property in partial class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-cascade

I have a mapping and POCOs as below. The problem is that `tbFNamesFeature` is not being updated when this object is saved (whereas `tblFeature` is)
I've tried different values for `cascade`, to no effect, so I'd have to say there's something I don't get. (see ??? in the xml).
What am I doing wrong?

`tbFNamesFeature` has 2 columns:

> FNamesId (PK, int, not null)
>   FeatureId  (PK, int, not null)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Feature, Infrastructure.Interface"
         table="tblFeature">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="FeatureId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" unique="true" index="PK_tblFeature" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Description" type="String">
      <column name="Description" length="100" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <bag name="FNames" table="tbFNamesFeature" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="???">
      <key>
        <column name="FeatureId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <many-to-many class="FName, Infrastructure.Interface">
        <column name="FNamesId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
      </many-to-many>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Feature.cs

```
public partial class Feature : System.IComparable
{
        protected int id;
        protected string description;

        public virtual int Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set { this.id = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Description
        {
            get { return this.description; }
            set { this.description = value; }
        }
}
```

Feature.part.cs

```
public partial class Feature : System.IComparable
{
        private System.Collections.Generic.IList<FName> fnames;

        public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<FName> FNames
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.fnames == null)
                {
                    this.fnames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<FName>();
                }
                return this.fnames;
            }
            set {
                this.fnames = value;
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited to reflect discussion**: As tblFNamesFeature is a many-to-many table, the mapping needs to be set up with inverse="false" to indicate that other end the relationship is not responsible for saving the collection.

cascade="all" also needs to be set (which covers saves, updates, and deletes).

Comment: Are you saying I need a mapping for `tbFNamesFeature `?

Comment: Yes. You need a mapping for every Entity/Table in your model. The only exception is pure many-to-many tables.

Comment: Actually, sorry I've just re-read your post. Is tbFNamesFeature supposed to be a many-to-many table? If so, what is it linking to?

Comment: Yes `tblFNamesFeature` is many-to-many. There is a table, `tblFNames`, which has `FNamesId` as it's PK (as does`tblFNamesFeature`). I have a mapping file for  'tblFNames'.

Comment: I think inverse="true" is saying that the other end of the relationship is responsible for the save. Try inverse="false".

Comment: This appears to be the solution, though let me test it some more.

Comment: The solution is inverse="true" AND cascade="all". If you will edit your answer to include this, I will check it off.